# USB Mounting Issue

Tags: usb

I'm new to Linux and Ubuntu and I don't know what to do.

I can't mount my USB drive. Every time I try, I get an "Not authorized to perform operation (udisks-error-quark, 4)"

What do I do?

Comment: What exactly do you do ? Click on "something" in file-manager or run command ? Please update your question with more details.

Answer (score 0):

Just go to the gnome disks utility and try to format as FAT32 then it shall work fine...
if you want to save data then firstly backup your data in other pc and then format as FAT32.
Sometimes in Ubuntu and Ubuntu based distros this problem have been faced.....